# How do i assign filename to a variable after unzipping unknown zip file in bash shell?

Tags: bash, shell

Here I have a zip file but I have no idea what the name it is. I want to assign filename to a variable after unzipping the zip file in bash shell but I got some message like

> Archive: name.zip inflating: ...inflating: ..

Here is my script and anyone knows whats the wrong with it?

```
filename=$(unzip -o *.zip)
echo $filename
```

Comment: Which is the file name don't you know: the name of the zip archive itself, or the name of some compressed file inside of the zip archive? Do you know how many files the archive contains?

Comment: @PierreFrançois The name of the zip archive itself. I should unzip the file at the current path using "unzip -o *.zip" but failed to assign the filename without ".zip" to a variable.

Comment: @HxH So there is only one zip file? If yes you can do `filename=*.zip`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: you have one ZIP file but you don't know its name. That ZIP file contains one directory at top level whose name you want to put into the variable `$filename`.

Try:

```sh
    filename=$(unzip -Z -1 *.zip | head -n1 | sed 's/\/$//')
    echo $filename
```

But if you are sure that the name of the top directory inside your ZIP archive is the same as the name of the archive itself without the suffix `.zip`, which is the default behaviour of `zip`, you can just try:

```sh
    filename=$(basename -s .zip *.zip)
    echo $filename
```

Comment: I noticed that your second command lists all the file inside the folder.. I know its confusing but please allow me explain my question again..for example, I have a zip file abc_v1.zip and in fact I don't know the zip file name. So I used "unzip -o *.zip" to unzip that zip file then I got a folder abc/ (again, I actually dont know what the folder name is)and it is possible to contain some other file like abc/inside, abc/infile and so on. What I want is just put "abc" the folder name after unzipping into the variable $filename. At last, I will get "abc" when I "echo $filename"..

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. As you can deduce from my answer above, I understood that there was only one file in your ZIP archive. Now you explain me there is only one *directory* at the top level inside this archive and you want to know the name of that directory. I will edit my answer according to that new information.

Comment: Thank you for your update. I got similar solution based on your original answer that "unzip -Z -1 *.zip | awk 'NR==1 {print}'" and I thought there was a more straightforward way. But thank you and it helps a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over the .zip files:

`for f in *.zip; do echo "unzipping $f"; unzip -o "$f"; done;`

(unzip will not return the name of the zip archive. Doing this will give you the name in $f.)